# Syntax Error (FROM) in Python, I do not want to use it as function but rather use it as to print something

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to print out usernames from Instagram. When I type in print i.from.username, there will be syntax error because Python thinks that I am using from function, which i actually not.

```
for i in a:
    print i.from.username
```

Is there anyway to troubleshoot it? I tried using making a string but it is still wrong. What I try to did was:

```
for i in a:
    print i+ ".from." +username
```

Base on the comments:

I'm not trying to put from as a key attribute. What I'm trying to do is collect data from Instagram API.

The a represents the comments, so basically I'm going into the comments to collect the usernames that commented.

```
        "text": "This is #kimsoohyun 's "house" in The Producer!",
        "from":  {
          "username": "lilingchen",
        },
```

If I put i.text, it will print out every comments. Now, I wanted to print out the username that commented, so I tried using i.from.username.

Comment: Can you post the complete traceback?

Comment: `from` is a keyword, not a valid identifier.

Comment: Don't use python keywords as attribute names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print getattr(i, 'from').username
```